# Accessing <td> in HTML Table Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to attach a row to an editable table using data from an array. In order to do this, I'm adding a row, then utilizing a save feature in order to manipulate the s of the row. My HTML table is:

```
<table id="tblData" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Treatment Number</th>
            <th>Cell Number</th>
            <th>Waste Container Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Being that the array data will be entered into the most recently added row, I've just accessed that  using the code below, however now I am struggling to access the actual  cells. My current code is:

```
function UpSave(rowData) {
    var tblData = document.getElementById("tblData");
    var lastRow = tblData.rows[tblData.rows.length - 1 ];
    var tdDate = lastRow.children("td:nth-child(1)"); 
    var tdTime = lastRow.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
    var tdTreatmentNum = lastRow.children("td:nth-child(3)"); 
    var tdCellNum = lastRow.children("td:nth-child(4)");
    console.log(par); 
    var tdWasteContNum = lastRow.children("td:nth-child(5)");
    var tdButtons = lastRow.children("td:nth-child(6)");

    tdDate.html(tdDate.children(data[rowData][0])); 
    tdTime.html(tdTime.children(data[rowData][1]));
    tdTreatmentNum.html(tdTreatmentNum.children(data[rowData][2]));
    tdCellNum.html(tdCellNum.children(data[rowData][3]));
    tdWasteContNum.html(tdWasteContNum.children(data[rowData][4]));
    tdButtons.html("<img src='trash.png' class='btnDelete'><img src='pencil.png' class='btnEdit'><img src='up.png' class='btnUp'><img src='down.png' class='btnDown'>"); 
};
```

but the .children at the end of the variables are not valid. Any ideas on what to have instead in order to access those  cells in the row?

(data is the array containing the text I'm putting into the )

Comment: Where is ``tblData`` defined?  Is there a getElementById('tblData') not shown?

Comment: No, I didn't know I had to define it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you never clearly defined the variable tblData by leaving out quotations when you do your original `getElementById`.  <s>Add this to</s> Replace the first line in the function:

```
    var tblData = document.getElementById("tblData");
```

Adding the quotations will bind the table in the DOM to the variable, then you can do the rest of the stuff.

Revised answer using jQuery:

```
    var $tblData = $("#tblData");
    var $lastRow = $tblData.find('tr').last();
    var $tdDate =  $lastRow.find('td').eq(1); 
    var $tdTime =  $lastRow.find('td').eq(2);
    var $tdTreatmentNum = $lastRow.find('td').eq(3);
    var $tdCellNum = $lastRow.find('td').eq(4);
    //console.log(par); 
    var $tdWasteContNum = $lastRow.find('td').eq(5);
    var $tdButtons = $lastRow.find('td').eq(6);


    $tdDate.html(data[rowData][0]); 
    $tdTime.html(data[rowData][1]);
    $tdTreatmentNum.html(data[rowData][2]);
    $tdCellNum.html(data[rowData][3]);
    $tdWasteContNum.html(data[rowData][4]);
    $tdButtons.html("<img src='trash.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='pencil.png' class='btnEdit'/><img src='up.png' class='btnUp'/><img src='down.png' class='btnDown'/>");
```

But, if you still want to use pure javascript, try changing the

```
   .children("td:nth-child(x)");
```

to

```
    .childNodes[x];
```

Edit note:  I changed the inside of the .html(...) function calls so just use the array directly.  Previously I had just copy/pasted the OP code for that portion.

Comment: I added that, but the children function is still invalid

Comment: Do you have the option of using jQuery here?  If so this becomes much MUCH simpler.

Comment: I can, as long as it maintains the overall design (adding the row to the table but in such a way that it doesn't obstruct the function of the editable table)

Comment: I update my answer using jQuery.  If you are only updating each cell once then there is no need to declare a variable first and then use .html() function, you can do them all at once.  Also, this could probably be compressed into a simple for loop for cells 1-5, just adjusting the indexes to match.

Comment: But, if you do want to use pure javascript, try .childNodes instead of the .children.

Comment: .childNodes doesn't seem to be working for me either. I'm running into a few bugs, but it may just be my code. I think your code needs $ before the variables in the first 5 of the last 6 lines of code

Comment: You have ``data[rowData][0]`` but the variable you are passing in is rowData not data.  Are you passing in a 2-d array or is data a global variable?

Comment: Yea, I ended up passing data too, but currently, jQuery can't read some of the array data (currently stuck on dates formatted as 07/30/2015)

Comment: Ok, I updated the code for that.  You should not have had all of the .children stuff inside of there, just the array itself.    Easiest way to format dates is cast them into a javascript Date object using ``var date = new Date('07/30/2015')`` and then you can use all of the methods for that class.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It's reading from a csv file, and haven't been able to make tdDate a new date without an error. But now, the format is reading, so I'll just make the input pure text. The buttons have stopped appearing though

Comment: The numbering for variables in your code just needs to stop at 0. That fixed the button problem. Thanks so much for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Np, glad I could help.